# Exibir uma lista de objetos java em linha

Tags: javascript

Boa noite.

Eu tenho um vetor java com nomes de frutas

Eu queria exibir as frutas em linha : banana, maçã, uva apresentando em uma tabela. 
Como faria isso usando javascript ?

```
 ${frutas[0].nome },${frutas[1].nome },${frutas[2].nome }
```

Usando isso acima caso tenha só duas frutas fica assim: **banana, maça,** 
Fica uma virgula no final. Queria evitar isso.

Comment: Amanda, dá uma reformulada na sua pergunta, explique melhor. Você está usando "JAVA"? Lembre-se que JAVA não tem nada a ver com JAVASCRIPT.

Answer (score 0):

Faça isso:

```
var frutasEmLinha = ""; 
frutas.forEach(function(fruta, index, array){
    frutasEmLinha += fruta.nome; 
    if(index < array.length - 1){
        frutasEmLinha += ', ';
    } 
});
```

Comment: Creio que "tente" não é uma forma concreta de resolver o problema.